# setInterval() won't stop if it gets called twice

Tags: javascript, timer, setinterval

What I'm trying to do is make slide out panels, but here is a simplified example of the problem I'm running into.

```
myCount = document.getElementById("counter")
myCount.onclick = startCount;
count = 0;

function startCount() { 
    timer = setInterval("countToTen()", 200);   
}

function countToTen() {

    count++;
    myCount.innerHTML = count;

    if (count >= 10) {
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
}
```

It works great if you click once. If you double click (and we can't trust users to only click when they're supposed to), then the counter goes on forever. I guess two timers got made, but Firebug is showing timer to always have the same id. So how do you use clearInterval correctly when setInterval got called twice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var timer;
function startCount() { 
    if (!timer) {
        timer = setInterval(countToTen, 200);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah okay, then you set timer to false when you do clearInterval and it's ready to get called again. I thought timer was more complicated than that, but apparently it's quite simple. Thanks!